# How to bulk update in FlaskSQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

This is request payload.
`{ "sender_ids": [ { "sender_id":"1234456", "value":1 }, { "sender_id":"17203157982", "value":1 } ] }`

I converted it into

```
mapping = {
  "1234456" : 1,
  "17203157982: : 1
}
```

My current Implementation

```
 query = db.session.query(SenderIdMap).filter(
        SenderIdMap.short_code.in_(mapping.keys()),
        SenderIdMap.source == source,
        SenderIdMap.is_deleted == 0
    )
for obj in query:
   obj.value = mapping.get(obj.short_code)
```

I want bulk update row from Table SenderIdMap, conditions are senderid should be matched in table and for matched rows i have to update the value of certain column.
But I dont want to do multiple queries, I want to do it in single query. I tried with bulk_update_mappings but it wont work because I will need to fetch the Id's for that rows first.
Also even if I managed to get IDs bulk_update_mappings is not working

Is there any other method to update any number of rows which will satisfy current use case?
Like values are mapped to rows. For each row a column can have different value to it.

My current Implementation

```
 query = db.session.query(SenderIdMap).filter(
        SenderIdMap.short_code.in_(mapping.keys()),
        SenderIdMap.source == source,
        SenderIdMap.is_deleted == 0
    )
for obj in query:
   obj.value = mapping.get(obj.short_code)
```

Also I tried this way

```
        app.logrotate.info(f"Inside for loop. {obj}")
        query = db.session.query(SenderIdMap).filter(
            SenderIdMap.short_code == obj.get("sender_id"),
            SenderIdMap.is_deleted == 0,
            SenderIdMap.source == source
        ).update(
            {
                SenderIdMap.value: obj.get("value")
            }
        )
        app.logrotate.info(f"out for loop. {obj}, query={query}")
```

As you can see this will make multiple queries. I want to do all this in single query.